# jQuery Find and Assign Index

Tags: jquery

I have an application which users can upload images. I did not like the default input file design so I changed it. I'm now working with two inputs, one that actually does select with file with type=file and another input which gets the value from type=file and puts it into type=text. This is fine if it's only one image I want to upload, but nope. Users can add more images, with a click of a link more file inputs appear.. this is where I'm having trouble. I'm trying to get the current index on a input which is being selected and assign it to its sister input, it works for the first input but after that, it stops working. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. See below link for live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/w6gmq2x5/

```
  // listens for a change in the value of a input[type=file]
  $('input[name^=filPostImg]').change(function() {
    // finds sister input[type=text] by matching index, and assigns value of input[type=file]
    $('input[name^=filPostPath]').eq($(this).index($(this))).val($(this).val());
  });
```

Edit: This question does not relate to adding inputs dynamically. It's about finding index keys and assinging values to sibling elements.

Comment: Why don't you use "multiple" to allow user to select and upload multiple files at once? You're actually building something really outdated, a long upload process that forces the user to manually select one file, then manually add  another file selector, then manually select a second file, and so on. This is "so 2003" some would say. Think about user experience first.

Comment: That's a very good point. I've been out of this game for a while now, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are looking for is the next sibling so

```
$(document).on('change','input[name="filPostImg[]"]',function() {
    $(this).next('input[name="filPostPath[]"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/54ktj30b/)